# How to Fetch data from and display notification in background?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-notifications

I am working on an android app. In which, I want to automate Notification. The way I am thinking is first,

1. Fetch data from the server, then
2. Store in Room DataBase, then
3. Get data from RoomDb and then Display Notification.

Repeat this every day at least once.

Now, I want this work done in the background under any condition. That is, whether the app in the background or whether the app is closed or whether the phone is restart.

So in any situation, Fetch data→Store it→Display Notification.

I found many android background processing libraries. Such as AlarmManager, JobScheduler, BroadcastReceiver, JobIntentService, Firebase Job Dispatcher, WorkManager, etc. I am working on API 19 to API 28 or higher. These libraries have limitations and having challenges in background processing.

So, which library will be suitable for me to build an Automate Notification which works well on API 19 to API 28 or higher.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[Jetpack WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager)**. It is backwards compatible up to API 14.

- WorkManager internally uses JobScheduler on devices with API 23+
  and a combination of BroadcastReceiver + AlarmManager on devices with API 14-22.
- Ensures task execution, even if the app or device restarts.